# How do you resize a dynamic template array?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic-arrays, template-classes

I have a dynamic template array as a member of my class. However, I can't resize the array in the constructor or in any other functions. I'm confused on the syntax. Here's the code:

```
template <class Type> class MaxHeapTree {
private:
    HeapNode<Type> *array[];
    HeapNode<Type> *root;
    int elementSize;
    int height;
    int leafCounter;
public: 
    // Constructor
    MaxHeapTree(int n = 10) : elementSize(0), height(0), leafCounter(0) {
        HeapNode<Type> *array = new HeapNode<Type>[n];
    }
```

The array is a an array of `HeapNode<Type>` objects included from the HeapNode class. Here's the constructor for the HeapNode class:

```
template <class Type> class HeapNode {
private:
    int key;
    Type value;
public:
    HeapNode(int key, Type const &value) {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
    }
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The same way you resize a "dynamic non-template array".

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with the shown code.

```
HeapNode<Type> *array[];
```

As described, this should be declared, simply:

```
HeapNode<Type> *array;
```

Then, in the constructor:

```
HeapNode<Type> *array = new HeapNode<Type>[n];
```

This declares a variable in the constructor function that's called "array". This does absolutely nothing to initialize a class member of that name. The constructor should simply be:

```
MaxHeapTree(int n = 10) : array(new HeapNode<Type>[n]), elementSize(0),
                          height(0), leafCounter(0)
{
}
```

Presumably, the array's size, `n`, should also be stored somewhere. But that part wasn't shown, in the question.

Furthermore, I would also question even the need to use dynamic allocation here. I see nothing here that cannot be accomplished by using a `std::vector`, in place of the dynamically-allocated array. Modern C++ code rarely needs to `new` or `delete` anything, especially arrays. Standard C++ containers eliminate the need for dynamic allocation in most cases. If `std::vector` was used here right from the beginning, this issue would not've happened in the first place.

Comment: I was tasked with using a dynamic array to create a heap tree. However, I've tried that initialization before and it won't compile.

Comment: "It won't compile" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: `MaxHeapTree.h: In instantiation of ‘MaxHeapTree<Type>::MaxHeapTree(int) [with Type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
main.cpp:14:61:   required from here
MaxHeapTree.h:22:98: error: no matching function for call to ‘HeapNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::HeapNode()’
 xHeapTree(int n = 10) : array(new HeapNode<Type>[n]), elementSize(0), height(0), leafCounter(0)`

Comment: HeapNode.h:14:2: note: candidate: HeapNode<Type>::HeapNode(int, const Type&) [with Type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
  HeapNode(int key, Type const &value) {
  ^
HeapNode.h:14:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
HeapNode.h:9:29: note: candidate: HeapNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::HeapNode(const HeapNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)
 template <class Type> class HeapNode {

Comment: This is because your `HeapNode` class does not have a default constructor. This has nothing to do with the array construction. You have to fix this, a separate issue, which has absolutely nothing to do with `MaxHeapTree`. No matter how you go about constructing an array, in `MaxHeapTree`'s constructor, it will not be possible until you fix this, too.

Comment: I've added a default constructor to the HeapNode class but it throws In function `MaxHeapTree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::MaxHeapTree(int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN11MaxHeapTreeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEC2Ei[_ZN11MaxHeapTreeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEC5Ei]+0x75): undefined reference to `HeapNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::HeapNode()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: This means you declared the default constructor, but did not define it.

Comment: Don't forget that template classes' constructor and destructor must be defined in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

Use a container to manage it:

```
std::vector<HeapNode<Type>> array
```